# MySQL Query to "flatten" or pivot table by fields

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am working with a WordPress plugin (formmaker) that saves form submissions in a table..

it has `id`, `form_id`, `element_label` (the input's ID), `element_value` (input value), `group_id` (the submission's ID), `date, and`ip`

From another table, I am able to get the assoc of **input id** and the **input name**

So, I am building my query like this...

```
SELECT group_id, form_id,
  (case WHEN element_label = 1 THEN `element_value` END) first_name,
  (case WHEN element_label = 3 THEN `element_value` END) last_name,
  (case WHEN element_label = 4 THEN `element_value` END) school_email,
  (case WHEN element_label = 5 THEN `element_value` END) contact_email
FROM `wp_formmaker_submits` 

WHERE `form_id` = 12
GROUP BY group_id, form_id
```

For some reason, it works for the first_name, but the other fields are null...

any help would be much appreciated!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using group by without aggregation function and for this you have unpredictable result 
you should use a (fake) aggregation function

```
  SELECT group_id, form_id,
    min((case WHEN element_label = 1 THEN `element_value` END))  first_name,
    min((case WHEN element_label = 3 THEN `element_value` END)) last_name,
    min((case WHEN element_label = 4 THEN `element_value` END)) school_email,
    min((case WHEN element_label = 5 THEN `element_value` END)) contact_email
  FROM `wp_formmaker_submits` 

  WHERE `form_id` = 12
  GROUP BY group_id, form_id
```

The use of  group by without aggregation function is deprecated  in sql and not allowed in the most recent version of mysql and in most of DB .. 
in this case the result for column not in aggreated  result is unpredicable tipically is the first value encountered  by sql engine for these columns

Comment: I tried to right away, but SO said I couldn't for 3 minutes... who knows..