# How pivot and merge these 2 tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have 2 wordpress tables that I am trying to merge using SQL, and one of them needs to be pivoted in order to merge (I think).

Table 1 is the Wordpress Users (users) table:

```
 ID | user_login | user_email | other_irrelevant_fields.  
 1  | john       | john@john  | ...   
 2  | mary       | mary@mary  | ...
 3  | eric       | eric@eric  | ....
```

Table 2 is the buddypress xprofile data (bp_xprofile_data) table:

```
 ID | user_id | field_id | value   
 1  | 1       | 1        | John is a guy.  
 2  | 3       | 1        | Eric is a man.  
 3  | 1       | 2        | John plays tennis.
```

I want to merge the two (by user_id) such that I get this result:

```
 
 user_ID | user_login | user_email | field1         | field2            | ...
 1       | john       | john@john  | John is a guy  | John plays tennis 
 2       | mary       | mary@mary  | null           | null
 3       | eric       | eric@eric  | Eric is a man  | null
```

I'm using phpmyadmin and mysql 5.6.41-84.1. Here's what I have tried to do - I'm not very good at SQL so I'm doing things a very "manual" way. I also tried searching other SO answers, but PIVOT is not recognised and most of them offer some variant on using PIVOT.

Tried:

> SELECT D.user_id ,  U.user_email, U.display_name, U.user_login, (SELECT D.value FROM `bp_xprofile_data` WHERE D.field_id =1) AS self_description, D.value FROM `bp_xprofile_data` WHERE D.field_id =2) AS sports FROM `bp_xprofile_data` D  JOIN `users` U ON U.`ID` = D.`user_id`

Obviously that doesn't work because the subquery returns the full list of matches for field_id=1 and not just a single result. But when I make the subquery have its own inner join (ugly!) the whole thing doesn't work either because the ID matching for the subquery and mainquery do not sync.

Any advice?

Comment: You might consider handling the display issue in application code instead

Comment: I'm also trying to learn more about mysql with this. Are you suggesting that what I'm trying to do is not possible in SQL though? If that's the case I'll just give up.
(Also, I tried exporting the whole database to excel and trying to merge it there but i'm even worse at excel than sql)...

Comment: All things are possible. Personally, I find dynamic sql a bit of a pain - although things are simpler if you're using MySQL 8+

Comment: any thoughts on how I should approach this problem? should i just export everything in raw sql and try and merge/pivot it elsewhere?

Comment: Not exactly what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680392/mysql-query-to-flatten-or-pivot-table-by-fields but the principal of 'flattening' the bp_xprofile_data is there - this would be a first step and you would then join the users table. You can research this by searching for MYSQL PIVOT WORDPRESS

Comment: Kinda interesting as an exercise.  But practically, then what? Are you going to write custom filters for every WP and BP function that handles users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of fields in bp_xprofile_data are unknown and variable the first step would be to get as many as there are then build a sql statement for submission
so

```
set @sql = (
select concat('select u.id,u.sname,user_id, ', gp,' from users u join bp_xprofile_data on u.id = user_id group by user_id')
from
(
select group_concat(
         concat('max(case when field_id = ',field_id,' then value  end) as field', field_id)
         )  gp
from  
(
select distinct field_id from bp_xprofile_data
) s
) t
);
```

where sub query s gets all the distinct fields from which a set of aggregate functions are built which are then augmented with the other bits to create a valid sql statement(which you can see by selecting @sql) which can then be submitted to dynamic sql -

```
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

note your users data is slightly different to mine so you will need to alter the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure out why concatenation is the method to use to "pivot" the table, but let me go through this slowly and learn. Appreciate it!

Comment: It isn't the concat that is important but the conditional aggregation it produces.